# How to find a series for comparison with $\sum 1/\sqrt{n(n+1)}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The series $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}$$
I have tried ratio and integral both lead me to inconclusive, so probably it's by comparisson but I can't find What to compare.

Comment: The integral test is inconclusive? What did you get for $$\int_1^{\infty}{dx\over\sqrt{x(x+1)}}$$

Answer (score 9):

Try a Limit Comparison with $\sum \frac{1}{n}$.

Along similar lines, note that $n(n+1)\lt n(4n)$, so $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}}\gt \dfrac{1}{2n}$.

The informal idea is that for large $n$, the number $\sqrt{n(n+1)}$ is roughly equal to $n$.

Comment: I get n/(sqrt(n(n+1))), I should simplifie more?

Comment: Yes, for the limit comparison you then divide top and bottom by $n$. You will get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}}$, and the limit is $1$. My second suggestion is more "concrete" so you may prefer it.

Comment: So for the limit comparison the algebraic "trick" one uses is $\sqrt{n(n+1)}=n\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}$.